# Need Help to setup angular in electron app

Tags: electron, angular8

I am looking for running the latest angular8 in the electron app.

My electron app runs but the angular does not get launched into the electron app.
I have followed all the steps given in the given link.
    https://www.sitepoint.com/build-a-desktop-application-with-electron-and-angular/

I get the electron app running but cannot see the angular structure, and in the console, there is error displayed as seen in the attach image

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue. I solved this by downgrade angular version from 8 to 7.2.1 and now it's working fine.
Steps:

```
sudo  npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean --force
sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.npm
sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.config
sudo  npm install -g @angular/cli@7.2.1
```

Comment: Yes even after I downgraded the angular version to 7.3.8, and that work. Looks like electron 5.0.3 is not compatible with angular 8.0 version.